# How can I get to a template's URL in Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia

For example in the [Kobe Bryant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobe_bryant) article, you can see that it uses the `Infobox NBA Player` template when you **View Source**. How can I get to the page of this template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply search for `Template:templatename` and you'll be brought to the page for the template in question.